# JBoss Problems on Windows with JBoss service start and CF9 Deployment!

Tags: deployment, windows-service, jboss, coldfusion

i have downloaded JBOSS 5.1 and unzipped it to c:\jboss-5.1.0.GA. I have installed  java jdk1.6.0_17 and i am using Windows XP SP3 (Dev-Environment) I have two problems.

I am not able to use it as a service.
I get the local JBoss website (http://127.0.0.1:8080) when i start Jboss manually by running c:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.bat. I can install the service (service.bat install) and it starts without errors but the local JBoss website (http://127.0.0.1:8080) is not reachable. I also tried the tanuki service wrapper without success.

The other problem concers EAR deployment.
When I run JBoss (manual start) i get the following error for coldfusion 9:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/cfusion.ear/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/cfusion.ear/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.SecurityException: Seed must be between 20 and 64 bytes. Only 8 bytes supplied.

        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:313)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:190)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:231)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:88)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:120)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.invokeOperation(AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:482)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):
```

I already tried to pass this to the JVM:

```
-Dcoldfusion.disablejsafe=true
```

But it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into that same problem. Open the service.bat file and look for 'set JAVA_OPTS=-Xrs' REM it out then save and close.

Below is a good guide on how to deploy CF9 on JBoss.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18c28-7fbd.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i am using glassfish v3 now, much easier to setup :)